# Sharing Texture between two opengl contexts

Tags: opengl, glx

I have created a window using GLFW3. I have created a child window using another thread with GLX. During GLX opengl context creation, I am passing the main windows opengl context (achieved by `glXGetCurrentContext`), as `sharelist` parameter to the opengl context of the child window, as I want to use the textures which are rendered by the child context in the main window. But I am getting this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Serial number of failed request:  38
  Current serial number in output stream:  39
```

As I saw in the `glxCreateContext` documentation,

> BadMatch is generated if the context to be created would not share the
>   address space or the screen of the context specified by shareList.

So, does this mean that I cannot share the texture with this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just noticed what is the problem. As one of GL Contexts are on One GPU and  the other one is on another GPU, it seems that I cannot share the display objects with each other. So, I have to use `glXCopyImageSubDataNV` to copy the texture from one gpu to another one.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  `glXCopyImageSubDataNV` just keeps crashing for me :(